# JSON-encoded PHP array submitted in hidden field of form - gives weird output when printed out in page to which the form is submitted

Tags: javascript, php, json, forms, post

In the following SSCCE, in `index.php`, a button is printed. When you click this button, a `form` is submitted (in the click listener of the `button` in JS) which contains one hidden `input` field, the value of which is `json_encode($anArray)`.

The `action` attribute of the form has a value of `test.php`, so the form is submitted to `test.php`.

In `test.php`, I print out the contents of `$_POST`, but I get this weird output:

**`Array ( [something] => { )`**

**The question is why, and what do I do to fix it?**

**The second question is that, at the moment `test.php` opens in new tab, can I force it to rather open in a new window?**

***test.php:***

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST["something"])) {
    print_r(  $_POST  );
} else {
    echo '$_POST["something"] is not set.';
}

?>
```

***script.js:***

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#someButton").click(function() {

    window.open('', 'TheWindow');   document.getElementById('TheForm').submit(); });

});
```

***index.php:***

```
<?php 

$dataToPass = array(
        "A" => array(
                1 => array(
                        "id" => 1,
                        "secondId" => 2,
                        "thirdId" => 3
                )
        ),


        "B" => array(
                1 => array(
                        "id" => 4,
                        "secondId" => 5,
                        "thirdId" => 6
                ),
                2 => array(
                        "id" => 7,
                        "secondId" => 8,
                        "thirdId" => 9
                )
        ),


        "C" => array(
                1 => array(
                        "id" => 10,
                        "secondId" => 11,
                        "thirdId" => 12
                )
        )

);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="scripts.js"></script>

</head>




<body>

<?php
print_r(json_encode($dataToPass));echo "<br><br>";//check
?>

<button id="someButton">Click me</button>

<form id="TheForm" method="post" action="test.php" target="TheWindow">
    <input type="hidden" name="something" value="<?php echo json_encode($dataToPass); ?>" />
</form>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do the name attributes on your form fields look like? What type of inputs are they? It's easier to understand the output by seeing the form html. Your form should not open in a new tab unless you specified so with `target` attr.. again hard to diagnose without the html

Comment: *"I get this wierd output"* ...what would you expect to see? Also note that opeing the same file in new window using script will initialize a new instance on server that won't have post data. Can use `target` on form

Comment: @DominicTobias Hey scroll down in the last code snippet, the HTML is there.

Comment: why do you not simple send data via $.ajax post ? set var value and after click send data to your php file.

Comment: You should use single-quote characters in the HTML markup for the JSON stuff assigned to the `value` attribute. If you don't, then the HTML parser will see double-quotes in your JSON and get confused.

Comment: @charlietfl Please scroll down in the last code snippet, the form HTML is there. There IS a `target` attribute.

Comment: Ah sorry missed that - remove the `target` attribute. Not sure what you mean by weird output - $_POST is an array with post values - why is that unexpected?

Comment: target would be more like `'_blank'` if you want form to open a new tab

Comment: @DominicTobias Weird because `json_encode($dataToPass);` in index.php prints: `{"A":{"1":{"id":1,"secondId":2,"thirdId":3}},"B":{"1":{"id":4,"secondId":5,"thirdId":6},"2":{"id":7,"secondId":8,"thirdId":9}},"C":{"1":{"id":10,"secondId":11,"thirdId":12}}}`. When I send it to `test.php` _as shown above in SSCCE_ I get a single opening curly bracket. See the output I posted before the code snippets in the question.

Comment: @charlietfl Weird because json_encode($dataToPass); in index.php prints: {"A":{"1":{"id":1,"secondId":2,"thirdId":3}},"B":{"1":{"id":‌​4,"secondId":5,"thir‌​dId":6},"2":{"id":7,‌​"secondId":8,"thirdI‌​d":9}},"C":{"1":{"id‌​":10,"secondId":11,"‌​thirdId":12}}}. When I send it to test.php as shown above in SSCCE I get a single opening curly bracket. See the output I posted before the code snippets in the question.

Comment: @Solace I've provided an answer to that mystery. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `<input>` tag should look like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="something" value='<?php echo json_encode($dataToPass); ?>' >
```

Note the use of single-quote characters instead of double-quotes for the `value` attribute. JSON strings contain double-quote characters; your HTML is reaching the browser looking like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="something" value="{"A":..." />
```

That's why all you get for the value is `{`.

Really, to be certain that things will work (the JSON *could* contain a single-quote too), you should use an HTML encoder to transform any embedded single- or double-quote characters into HTML entities. That way you're guaranteed that the final HTML will not confuse the HTML parser.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Pointy, thank you so very much indeed!

Comment: Can you answer my second question as well? How do I force `test.php` to open in a new Window, rather than a new tab?

Comment: @Solace well unfortunately you can't; control over how the browser puts content in tabs or separate windows is under end user control.

Comment: what if there's a single quotation mark in the encoded string? like below example of html attribute 

`value='{"A": "De heer L'ohMaan"}' `

browser console will throw this error

**`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`**

Comment: @BattleHawk that's what I meant by recommending using HTML encoding for the attribute values. If all the embedded quotes in the HTML attribute value are expressed as HTML entities (`&#34;` for double-quote, `&#39;` for single-quote) then the HTML parser will rectify those into the actual characters and there's no ambiguity as to where the attribute value begins and ends. In JSON, an embedded single-quote is fine and requires no escaping.

Comment: @BattleHawk in your specific case, `value='{&#34;A&#34;: &#34;De heer L&#39;ohMaan&#34;}'`

Comment: The note about value='single-quote' saved me!